# When I change arguments in a method other classes which are calling same very method get disturbed

Tags: java, class, methods, interface, arguments

I have three classes for now one is the main class,

**Class A:**

```
class A{
  int result;    
  
  int getHeightBase() {
    return result;
  }

  void setHeightBase(int h, int b) {
   result=h*b;
  }
}
```

**Class B:**

This class will perform different calculations than A

```
class B{
  int result;

  int getHeightBase() {
    return result;
  }

  void setHeightBase(int h, int b) {
   result=12*h*b;
  }
}
```

**MainClass:**

```
public class Main {    

  public static void main(String[] args) {

   A a= new A();    
   B b= new B();    
  calculateArea(a,b);    
  }

void calculateArea(A obj1, B obj2){    
  obj1.setHeightBase(5,6);    
  obj2.setHeightBase(5,6);
}

}
```

Now, when I change arguments of class A method **setHeightBase** or class B method **setHeightBase** for some reason I got to change in MainClass as well where I am sending integer values , and I think this opposes design patterns, could anyone please guide me how to get rid of this, I want to change arguments later on but I don't want to effect any other class or change any  other class, I tried to use interface but did not get how to get rid of this problem
thanks a lot in advance , any help would be appreciated

Comment: "I think this opposes design patterns", no, it doesn't, there is no design pattern used here. You have to send the parameters expected, that's the basics of how it works. "I want to change arguments later on, but I don't want to effect any other class" create a new overloaded method with the changed signature

Comment: please provide example , I am beginner so it would help me a lot,  but as you said let's say other 20 classes are calling this method and sending Integer values as MainClass , what if I change the signature of method and reduce or increase some arguments , then I would have to change all other 20 files as well to make it work, don't you think so it is a bad practice ?

Comment: how is that "bad practice"? You expect calling non existent methods good practice?

Comment: No, I mean is there a way we change only one file and all other files will be updated automatically, any interface which is taking that function whose arguments can be changed something like that , ?

Comment: as I said: overload your method. I've shown an example in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this class:

```
public void printNumbers(int one, int two) {
  int result = one + two;
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

And this is being called from multiple other classes. You can't just change the signature (returntype, method name, parameterlist) and expect everything to work just fine.

Now, let's assume you don't want it to automatically print a sum, but you want to be able to choose what action to take addition or subtraction.

For the current method, don't change anything. It's been used for addition. So, you'll add an overloaded method, which accepts an additional parameter:

```
public void printNumbers(int one, int two) {
  int result = one + two;
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
}

public void printNumbers(int one, int two, String action) {
  // action is either add or sub
  if ( !"add".equals(action) && !"sub".equals(action) ) {
    System.out.println("Error");
  } else if ("add".equals(action) {
    int result = one + two;
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
  } else {
    int result = one - two;
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
  }
}
```

Once you did that, you can change the original method to:

```
public void printNumbers(int one, int two) {
  printNumbers(one, two, "add");
}

public void printNumbers(int one, int two, String action) {
  // action is either add or sub
  if ( !"add".equals(action) && !"sub".equals(action) ) {
    System.out.println("Error");
  } else if ("add".equals(action) {
    int result = one + two;
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
  } else {
    int result = one - two;
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
  }
}
```

and the functionality that was once provided will remain the same, while you won't have to change any other existing code

Answer (score 0):

You can use method overloading,

```
  void setHeightBase(int h, int b) {
     result=12*h*b;
  }

  void setHeightBase(double h, double b) {
     result=12.0*h*b;
  }
```

this will save the previous method and also creates a method with exact name and different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an abstract class as the base and extend other classes from it. The public methods in the abstract class will act as the contract to the outside world. In future, if you want to expose other method you add them to the interface and depending on the functionality, you could provide a default implementation. In real world scenarios, you avoid changing an existing contract.

As an example, your classes can be written as such

```
abstract class Shape{
    int height;
    int base;
    
    Shape(int height, int base){
        super();
        this.height = height;
        this.base = base;
    }
    
    public int area(){
        return height * base;
    }
    
}

class Shape1 extends Shape{

    Shape1(int height, int base){
        super(height, base);
    }
}

class Shape2 extends Shape{
    
    Shape2(int height, int base){
        super(height, base);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int area(){
        return 12 * height * base;
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Shape s1 = new Shape1(2,3);
        Shape s2 = new Shape2(2,3);
        System.out.println(s1.area());
        System.out.println(s2.area());
    }
}
```